# Hudson - Windows Batch Script -Build

Tags: hudson

i am running build via windows batch script. if build fails it not sending mail to developers, who broke the build.
can you help me.
Regards 
Akilan

Comment: There is more information needed to form a good answer.  Does Hudson mark the build as failed?  Does the batch command return a non-zero value if it fails?  Have you tested that e-mail works from the main Hudson configuration window?

Answer (score 1):

Make your batch script set an exit code (Error level) signalling success or failure of the batch script. This should indicate to hudson that the batch file failed. Exiting with a zero error level indicates success, and nonzero indicates failure. If your batch file calls other applications (compiler etc.) you might be able to use their respective exit codes to set the error level of your batch file.

For example

```
@echo off
compiler.exe sourcefile.abc
exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

The last line would return the exit code of compiler.exe as the return code of your batch file. 
If you have multiple executions in your batch file, you can test the errorlevel between each exceution with `IF ERRORLEVEL` and fail whenever you detect a nonzero errorlevel.

Also, remember to test the email sending functionality using the test tool found where you configure smtp server etc. inside the hudson/jenkins config.

Comment: Thanks Andres, after this also hudson not sending mail to recipents. getting this error " An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored. "
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: If you look on the build overview (http://www.beroux.com/articles/hudson/hudson-build-screenshot.png) at the "changes" section of the failed build, are there any changes reported that triggered the build? If you click on the detail-links of the changes, can you see which users committed the change(s)? If so, if you click on the user names for the change, does that user have an email address configured in hudson so that hudson knows where to send the email?

Comment: Thanks Andres a lot!!!  i have marked this (enabled) Send separate e-mails to individuals who broke the build If this option is checked, the notification e-mail will be sent to individuals who have committed changes for the broken build (by assuming that those changes broke the build). If e-mail addresses are also specified in the recipient list, then both the individuals as well as the specified addresses get the notification e-mail.  " If the recipient list is empty, then only the individuals will receive e-mails". can you explain this scenario

Comment: Your email sending configuration seems to be correct Aki, but I need the answers to the 3 questions in my previous comment in order to help you.

Comment: 1) daily checkins hapenning, and am triggering once in day. 2)in detail-link i cannot see any thing as you told no 3)mail ids configured so far because of the following reasons the folowing information taken from Email-Notification option ............. If this option is checked, "If the recipient list is empty, then only the individuals will receive e-mails."

Comment: 1) daily checkins hapenning, and am triggering once in day.
2)in detail-link i cannot see any thing as you told 
3) mail ids not configured so far because of the following reasons 
the folowing information taken from 
Email-Notification option 
............. 
If this option is checked, "If the recipient list is empty, then only the individuals will receive e-mails."

Comment: So there has been changes in your build, but hudson is not picking up *who* has changed the build? Are you using svn? Are you using "poll svn" to check for changes once per day, and build only if there are changes? If you check the check box, emails will only go to those individuals that committed changes to the failed build. If Hudson does not know who committed to a particular build, and what their email addresses are, it cannot send emails to them.

Comment: i am using CVS. i have windows script to run the build. i have selected none for Source Code Management. then only Execute Windows Batch Command. batch script have checkout script, compilation, jar generation. kindly help me whats need to be done to send out mail automaticaly.

Comment: You should probably let Hudson handle the polling & checkout from CVS (With the Hudson CVS plugin). Otherwise it cannot know who has committed to a build! Remove the CVS things from your batch file and enter the appropriate things into the Hudson configuration for Source Code Management.

Comment: so i need to rewrite my build, ok fine. thanks for your help Anders.  you vast experience gives more (immediate)clarity on this for me. once again Thanks Anders Forsgren